# put a component in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I need to "duplicate" when I press a button, they have recommended that I use the .push but I don't understand, the example they gave me is this `[<Component />]` and you are doing push
`.push(<Component />)`, the component that I want to "duplicate" is `Dropzone` every time I click the `Button`:

```
export default function Registration() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full text-sm relative">
      <InputTitle className="mb-4">Documentación</InputTitle>
      <div className="w-full flex items-center justify-between border-t border-b border-dark-15 p-4">
        <SingleDropdown>Selecciona tipo de documento</SingleDropdown>
        <div className="flex justify-end">
         [ <Dropzone />]
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-end items-center pr-4 pt-8 h-9">
        <Button.Secundary className="" onClick={()=>.push(<Dropzone />)}>
          Agregar otro documento
          <BsPlus className="ml-2 text-2xl font-bold" />
        </Button.Secundary>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Use state with an array

Comment: u need to assign dropzone to a state and update the state by pushing the dropzone to an array.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know that much, and I don't know what it would be like, as you say

Comment: `[ <Dropzone />]` is not correct way of displaying the components. You can create an array before the return statement with one `DropZone component. On every click, update the array using push method of that array. And render the array using map function.

Comment: can you give an example? sorry for my ignorance I'm still learning @kay

Comment: Look at @Phoenix1355 's example. that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the dropdowns to an array that can be rendered in the HTML. You do that in functional components by using [`React.useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook. You can use that to save the previously added dropdowns for each time the component re-renders. With that, it is also possible to add a new dropdown each time the user clicks on the button.

I've provided an example below.

```
export default function Registration() {
  const [dropdowns, setDropdowns] = React.useState([]);

  const addDropdown = (component) =>
    setDropdowns((prev) => [...prev, component]);

  return (
    <div className='w-full text-sm relative'>
      <InputTitle className='mb-4'>Documentación</InputTitle>
      <div className='w-full flex items-center justify-between border-t border-b border-dark-15 p-4'>
        <SingleDropdown>Selecciona tipo de documento</SingleDropdown>
        <div className='flex justify-end'>
          {dropdowns}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex justify-end items-center pr-4 pt-8 h-9'>
        <Button.Secundary
          className=''
          onClick={() => addDropdown(<Dropzone />)}
        >
          Agregar otro documento
          <BsPlus className='ml-2 text-2xl font-bold' />
        </Button.Secundary>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```